# popover when UITextField starts editing

Tags: iphone, xcode4.5

Can any one help me when UItextField starts editing have to show popover .

Iam new to this programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See you have a `UITextField` in that set the delegates to self.

```
[textField setDelegate : self];
```

then use the delegate

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
 {
   // call the method where u r making ur popover
 }
```

This delegate is called when you starting writing in the `UITextField`.

Comment: Can we use popover in iphone

Comment: but u can always create custom popover by using views and loading table views in it

Comment: Can you help me out from my problem

Comment: my requirement is when textfield was editing i want to show tableview and when we click on the tableview cell get that information in to textfield and that works well but when click on screeen have to hide tableview that is not working good.so,am trying to do this using popover .

Comment: see problem her if you use a popover in iphone then u need to custom views and table view in that way you r just complicating things better use a table view and there is this delegate of table view       DidSelectATROWFORINDEXPATH WRITE THE SELECTION THING DER

Comment: I WOULD ACTUALLY SUGGEST YOU NOT TO USE POPOVER THAT WILL COMPLICATE THINGS

Comment: thx for ur suggestion i tried it using custom view ,for customview as it is subview to my main viewcontroller  either,hiding tableview when click on screen(other than textfield) or getting value when click on tableview only one is esponding

Comment: U COULD HAVE DONE THE SAME THING IN didSelectForRowAtIndexPath after selection u could have hidden the table view

Comment: no,i already did the process that you said.am able to hide Uitableview after selecting the row of tableview and all thats working fine.unable to hide table view when click on emppty screen and it is a static tableview after hiding the tableview  i cant access the textfields and buttons in that are present in table view area

Comment: after loading the table view cell value to textfield am unhiding the tableview

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of textfield delegate method to show your popover as soon as textfield starts editing

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
 {
   [self showPopOver];
 }
```

Note:- showPoperOver is a custom method.

OR

You can notification observer for notification

```
UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification
```

Comment: If you want to show a UIPopoverController, then you can follow Manohar answer mentioned above

Comment: yes it will worked on ipad since UIPopoverController isonly present in ipad.If you want to implement a popover in iphone then you have to make ur own custom view like a popover...

Comment: can you help me out from this..........my requirement is when textfield was editing i want to show tableview and when we click on the tableview cell get that information in to textfield and that works well but when click on screeen have to hide tableview that is not working good.so,am trying to do this using popover

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self showPopOverController];
}
- (void)showPopOverController
{
    self.imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.imgPicker.delegate = self;
    self.imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    _popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:self.imgPicker];
    [_popover setDelegate:self];
    [_popover presentPopoverFromRect:self.txtField.frame  inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
}
```

Where you need to declare in .h file

```
 UIPopoverController *_popover;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtField;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) UIImagePickerController *imgPicker;
```

**This works only for iPad**

Comment: Instead of ImagePicker make your own ContentViewController.

Comment: @prathyusha: I had seen your previous question i got to know what is your actual requirement.

Comment: @prathyusha: iPhone does not support UIPopOverController. Only iPad supports that.

Comment: i want it for both ipad and iphone cant we do that.

Comment: @prathyusha: can i know what's your requirement ? So that i can give you an idea

Comment: my requirement is when textfield was editing i want to show tableview and when we click on the tableview cell get that information in to textfield and that works well but when click on screeen have to hide tableview that is not working good.so,am trying to do this using popover

Comment: @prathyusha: Is it the same requirement for iPhone too ?

Comment: @prathyusha: you need to make a custom class and hope so this links helps you. just run the code. after running the code just copy the classes and integrate the code. It Will work fine... https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover